# Resetting System.in/out

Tags: java, final

If System.out and System.in are made final so that we do not change them, then why do we have the methods `System.setIn` and `System.setOut`? Isn't the following statement contradictory?

> `System.in` and `System.out` are
>   accessible directly without accessor
>   methods. But they are not directly
>   redirectable to other streams because
>   they are `final`. But we do have setter
>   methods to set them to some other
>   streams.

If they are `final` why even let them be reset? Or if we need them to be able to reset to some other streams why have them `final` in first place? Instead of directly accessing them why not let users write `System.getIn()` and `System.getOut()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically looking at design warts left over from the very early days of Java. The fields existed in Java 1.0 (presumably already public and final), and when the designers realized that they needed a way to redirect them it was too late to change because that would have broken pretty much every single Java program in existence.

Java's design has always valued downwards compatibility above all else, so in Java 1.1 they added the set methods as workaround instead (making the fields non-final would just have made the design flaw worse, at least this way the set methods can e.g. do a permissions check).

Answer (score 1):

The `setXXX` methods are using some VM-internal magic to do things normally not possible, namely changing final variables. (It would be possible without such magic, if the final Streams were only wrappers around the real streams, with privately changable wrapees.)

Advantages of this design compared to simple non-final fields:

- The methods can ask the installed SecurityManager to check whether the caller has the necessary permissions to change the streams.

Compared to simple `get` + `set` methods (and private fields):

- It is shorter to write.
- More important, as Michael said: compatibility to old code. The `setXXX` methods were added later.

Answer (score 0):

I've had no problem in the past swapping in classes for in, out and err. It's been useful in some situations where I was testing command line classes. I cannot remember whether I used the set*() method or just directly set the streams. But it was easy to do.

Comment: You used the `set*` methods.  The fields are declared as `final`.